# Exclude subset of network in BIND Named acl

Tags: bind, access-control-list

I'd like to exclude some IPs from an acl, eg:

```
acl "exclude" {
  192.168.1.1;
  192.168.1.2;
  192.168.1.3;
};

acl "internal" {
  192.168.1.0/24;
  !exclude;
};
```

This doesn't work, I think because IPs contained in exclude acl are contained in the whole range.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a "!" before the IPs that you want to exclude. If you want to exclude all IPs from "exclude" acl, change it to this:

```
acl "exclude" {
  !192.168.1.1/24;
  !192.168.1.2/24;
  !192.168.1.3/24;
};
```

Comment: /24 ? are you sure ? I tried without netmask, 24 or 32, none work. I also tried with !exclude; or exclude; without luck.  Just by putting !exclude first seems to work though.

Comment: add a "any;" to the end.

Answer (score 0):

BIND ACLs use "first-match" logic rather than "best-match." Your "internal" ACL does not work as you expect because the *first* address element matches all of the addresses that you wish to exclude, *and then everything following (i.e. the* `!exclude;`  *element) is ignored*.

You just need to switch the order, as follows:

```
acl "internal" {
  !exclude;
  192.168.1.0/24;
};
```

This very issue is discussed in the [official BIND 9.11 Administrators’ Reference Manual](https://www.isc.org/bind-9-11-arm/), at Section 7.1 regarding security considerations for properly implemented ACLs.